# Angular 6 CLI adding new component to app.modules.ts causes a white screen

Tags: javascript, typescript, components, angular-cli, angular6

I was creating a web app that required login and registration and i decided to use the code below. when I clone it and use npm start it works perfectly fine, but when i create or import a component and add it in the app.modules.ts file, all i see is a loading... on the top left of a white screen. I have been trying to fix this for hours but i cant fix this. can someone please let me know how i can create and use an angular component in this project.

github link: https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-6-registration-login-example-cli

Comment: please set your code in stackblitz

Comment: @לבני מלכה the code has multiple files so i put the link to the gitgub. its exactly the same as the github link i posted in the description